# How to collect payment for an android project using firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, payment-gateway

We need to accept payment for my android project without using another server, We are using firebase.if we are using PHP server then, we know to implement payment gateway but for firebase, we couldn't found any solution

Comment: Firebase doesn't provide a payment service. You'll have to use your own server

Comment: Tried firebase functions? You can host your own node.js server in Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Cloud Functions for Firebase examples published by the Firebase team, in particular the one which shows how to integrate with Stripe:

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe

By analysing this example together with the Stripe documentation https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/sources, you will discover that it is quite easy to create a source object from your Android app and then create a charge through a cloud function.